# I want to automate the Android Hybrid app in JavaScript. But not able to open it in webview

Tags: node.js, webdriver, appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

I have added all the required capabilities but nothing happens.

`autoWebview: true,
setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled: true,`

When I use this one in the capabilities, it gives me an error that deriver is not defined.

`driver.getContexts().then(function (contexts) { // get list of available views. Returns array: [“NATIVE_APP”,“WEBVIEW_1”]
return driver.context(contexts[1]); // choose the webview context })`

And after adding this under the section I want to open it gives me this error:

**TypeError: driver.getContexts(…).then is not a function**

Comment: Have you by any chance forgot to put/close "()" after ```.then``` ?

Comment: @curiousMinded its the same code that is available on Appium office site.